# Program based on functions in Python

Tags: python

```
def add_sub(x,y):
    d=x+y
    e=x-y
    return d,e
result=add_sub(7,6)
print(result)
```

The output for this function is `(13,1)`, but i need output as mentioned below:

```
13
1
```

Comment: Then you have to print the values independently, or in a loop, or `'\n'.join()` them, or …

Comment: `print(result[0])` `print(result[1])`

Answer (score 0):

It needs to be like this:

```
def add_sub(x,y):
    d=x+y
    e=x-y
    return d,e
result=add_sub(7,6)
for val in result:
    print(val)
```

Since the `result` is returned on the `tuple`, `tuple` prints on that small braces.

Also, you can do this:

```
def add_sub(x,y):
    d=x+y
    e=x-y
    return d,e
result=add_sub(7,6)
print("\n".join(map(str, result)))
```

Answer (score 0):

When your function returns an iterable (a tuple in your case), and you know how many elements it will have, you can unpack it very easily:

```py
def add_sub(x, y):
    d = x + y
    e = x - y
    return d, e
result_add, result_sub = add_sub(7,6)
print(result_add)
# 13
print(result_sub)
# 1
```